# mod_fcgid.so module not loading with apache 2.4 after upgradation of MAC OSX yosemite

Tags: macos, apache, mod-fcgid, mod-fastcgi, fcgid

I have upgraded osx 10.8 to 10.10 yosemite.
After up gradation I found that apache version also upgraded from 2.2 to 2.4.

The only thing I found in apache 2.4 that the loadmodule section in apache configuration file for FastCGI giving error and FastCGI module not loaded with apache.

I have also reinstall mod_fcgid.so but its not worked.

The error is following...

```
$ sudo apachectl -T
httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_fcgid.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_fcgid.so, 10): Symbol not found: _unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_fcgid.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_fcgid.so
```

Can anyone help me on this? How can I configure FastCGI on apache version 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on Mac OS 10.11 El Capitan, and fixed it by recompiling mod_fcgid.so. You can download the source from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#mod_fcgid and then read its README-FCGID file. That is, in Terminal `cd` into the directory you downloaded, and then do

```
./configure.apxs
make
```

I got a couple errors, similar to those discussed in https://gist.github.com/justin-schroeder/d3ef404e80a7ae658a8d and so I fixed them similarly:

```
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: line 1111: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.11.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
```

so I did:

```
pushd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains
ls
sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.11.xctoolchain
popd
make

/usr/include/apache2/ap_hooks.h:39:10: fatal error: 'apr.h' file not found

pushd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
ls
sudo ln -s MacOSX10.11.sdk MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk
popd
make
```

This worked for me, but on El Capitan the `make install` final step didn't work, as discussed in the above justin-schroeder link, so I worked around that as he suggested.